# SSIS - DT_IMAGE Data type export out to a flat file. Getting an error

Tags: ssis

Getting an The data type for "input column "image_full" (105)" is DT_IMAGE, which is not supported. Use DT_TEXT or DT_NTEXT instead and convert the data from, or to, DT_IMAGE using the data conversion component. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard).  Any way to resolve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create the SSIS package by hand in VS and use the data conversion component. Since DT_IMAGE is not supported the wizard is not going to work.

**This is what the data conversion component looks like**

[[image: Data conversion component[1]]

Comment: Thank you but what data type should I convert it to?  I will need it exported out to a .csv file.

Comment: Awesome =) SSIS is not always this easy =P

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS, use DT_TEXT to convert the column with DT_IMAGE

[image]